# Sum in Laravel Eloquent and Return on Page

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm trying to get the location's inventory value with the following eloquent query. It properly pulls up everything (location name, address, # of users, etc) except the inventory value which returns null. I first built this query in SQL which works great but for whatever reason doesn't work in eloquent. It was the same exact query.

```
$locations = \App\Models\Location::select(DB::raw('locations.*', 'SUM(inventory.part_price * inventory.quantity) AS inventory_value'))
            ->leftJoin('inventory', 'locations.id', '=', 'inventory.location_id')
            ->where('locations.company_id', '=', Auth::user()->company_id)
            ->groupBy('locations.id')
            ->get();
```

On the blade file, I'm using a `@foreach` loop. I try using `{{$location->inventory_value}}` which returns null. I've tried to dump that particular variable in the controller and it is null there too. The blade file looks like this:

[image]

It should be returning the inventory value of all of the following:

[image]

Ultimately my question is how do I fix this query to get the sum of the inventory price and quantity to show on the blade file? Thanks!

Comment: I can't get `inventory_value` to show on the blade file. It also returns null in the controller before it even hits the blade file. (see the empty cell on the picture and additional picture I just added).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `DB::raw` pass all your columns as the first parameter (within the same quote) like:

```
DB::raw('locations.*, SUM(inventory.part_price * inventory.quantity) AS inventory_value')
```

You can also use `selectRaw` to make it look cleaner like:

```
use App\Models\Location;

$locations = Location::selectRaw('locations.*, SUM(inventory.part_price * inventory.quantity) AS inventory_value')->leftJoin...
```

Comment: Oooooh my gosh, I spent days coming back to this in hopes to grind out some complicated answer. It always seems to be the simple things! That fixed my problem, thank you SO much! I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @JustinHammond No problem, expanded the answer a little more.